# Vuefire retrieve data from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuefire

I have the following firebase structure

[image]

Am trying to retrieve the value of latest_version in vuejs

So I have my configuration as

```
import Firebase from 'firebase';

let config = {
    //firebase config
};
let firebaseApp = Firebase.initializeApp(config)

export const db = firebaseApp.database();
```

In the vuejs2 component I have added the import as

```
     import {db} from './helpers/firebase'

      export default {

       firebase: {
        latestversion: {
          source: db.ref('latest_version'),

         }
        }, 
         mounted(){
           console.log("latest_version is", this.latestversion) ///this doesnt give me the value 1.0.0

          }

       }
```

What else must I do to get the value 1.0.0 from firebase, as the above console log doesn't

Comment: Looks like an async issue:  `mounted()` is firing before the firebase data has been retrieved.